# Show/Hide breaks image scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an image scroller plugin within a set of divs that are set to randomly show when the page is loaded and then show/hide when an image/logo is clicked on.  What I am noticing is that the thumbnail scroller breaks when it's not the first div to be loaded on the page or when another slider is shown.
Here's a link to a demo that I'm working on:
http://sjdunham.com/test/yzn/

I am assuming that it's because of the way that the plugin is loaded:

```
$(function($){
   window.onload=function(){
```

Since the page is not being reloaded when the divs are shown and hidden and that it only load up for the first div item.

I'm not sure what I would need to change in order for the plugin to load all the div's correctly

Comment: Everytime the page is loaded, it will randomly show a gallery.  Then when a user clicks on one of the images, it will hide the current div and show another one with the other gallery in it.  And so on and so forth.  So far, the thumbnail slider only works for the first div in the code.  Any other sliders below it will not work properly.

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code here? Otherwise this question will be useless to future visitors once you remove /test/yzn/

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate ID's, ID's must be unique. Try using a className instead.

```
<div class="tS2">...</div>
<div class="tS2">...</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tS2").thumbnailScroller({...});
});
</script>
```

Comment: thats what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure and wanted to get a 2nd opinion.  I will try that and see if that works.  thanks for your input. This is still very new to me so I appreciate all the help.